# Multiple SELECT followed by multiple UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update, average

I have two tables - 1st table `gas_emissions`, 2nd table - `regiony_avg`.

Table `gas_emissions` has columns `region`, `region_id`, `data_val`, `year`.

Table `regiony_avg` has columns `region_id`, `avg_region`.

There are multiple values for each region because they're calculated every year. I need to calculate AVG for each region and insert it into `regiony_avg`.

There are over 10 regions, what I've done is

```
SELECT AVG(data_val) AS AKL 
FROM gas_emissions 
WHERE region_id = 'AKL'
```

and then

```
UPDATE regiony_avg 
SET avg_region = 1999.64771428571 
WHERE region_id = 'AKL'
```

I did it for each of regions. However I can't see how to do it if there are for example 1000 regions. Is there any way to get AVG for all unique `regions` at and then insert it into `regiony_avg` at once?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into regiony_avg (region_id, avg_region)
    selet region_id, avg(data_val)
    from gas_emissions
    group by region_id;
```

Note:  I see little reason to store this information in a table when it can easily be calculated using an aggregation query.  In fact, you can add the average to each row of the original table using window functions:

```
select ge.*,
       avg(data) over (partition by region_id) as region_avg
from gas_emissions ge;
```